# Post is Sending Blank Values

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to insert user input from drop down boxes into my database. I am using this code for the form to dynamically generate options from the database. And it is continued for player1 through to player11, but all use the same code so I will just include an example of player1 for the interests of space:

```
<form action="teamCreate.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" name="teamCreation" method="post">                      
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Player 1:
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="player1" name="player1">'; 
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT playerName FROM Player");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {
                echo "<option value=\"player\">" . $row['playerName'] . "</option>";
            }
            echo '</select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is what I do with it in teamCreate.php:

```
$player=array(); //Creates an array of players, using the values posted from editTeam.php
$player[1]=$_POST['player1'];
$player[2]=$_POST['player2'];
$player[3]=$_POST['player3'];
$player[4]=$_POST['player4'];
$player[5]=$_POST['player5'];
$player[6]=$_POST['player6'];
$player[7]=$_POST['player7'];
$player[8]=$_POST['player8'];
$player[9]=$_POST['player9'];
$player[10]=$_POST['player10'];
$player[11]=$_POST['player11'];

$teamName = $_SESSION['teamName'];
$counter=1;
while ($counter < 12) //Creates a loop that goes through the player array, adding them to the database under the user's team name
        {
            $currentPlayer = $player['$counter'];
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO PlayerListing(teamName, playerName)VALUES('$teamName', '$currentPlayer')");
            $counter = $counter + 1;
        }
```

When I look at the results in the database, the teamName Column is set correctly for all of the added rows, however the playerName column is blank. I have been puzzling over this for hours, and I do not understand what the problem is.

Thanks, Wolffe.

Comment: 1) You aren't changing the `value` attribute of your `<option>` fields. 2) You should be running one big insert instead of 11 separate queries, which will kill performance.

Comment: please echo first the players value that you received before you do an insertion. Just to make sure the value passed correctly.

Comment: You should **really** consider a newer MySQL library like MySQLi or PDO.  The `mysql_*` family of functions are deprecated.  If this is a new project I would recommend making the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this chunk of your code:

```
while ($counter < 12) //Creates a loop that goes through the player array, adding them to the database under the user's team name
{
     $currentPlayer = $player['$counter'];
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO PlayerListing(teamName, playerName)VALUES('$teamName', '$currentPlayer')");
     $counter = $counter + 1;
}
```

When you assign your `$currentPlayer` you are using single quotes and encasing a variable name within it.  It looks like you want to value of `$counter` right there, but you cannot do so with single quotes, only double quotes will interpolate variable values for you.  To fix this you must either remove the quotes altogether (which is what I would recommend) or encase that variable with double quotes.

```
while ($counter < 12) //Creates a loop that goes through the player array, adding them to the database under the user's team name
{
     $currentPlayer = $player[$counter];
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO PlayerListing(teamName, playerName)VALUES('$teamName', '$currentPlayer')");
     $counter = $counter + 1;
}
```

The problem is that your index of `$counter` (literally, not as a variable) contains no value, hence no value is getting inserted into the database.